# When to change oil for new generation Mazda?

Tags: mazda, oil-change, mazda-3

I have a 2021 Mazda3 and MyMazda app is showing that I need to change my oil soon.

I had an oil change at 4600 miles and it's telling me to change oil at 7600 miles, and it's currently at 7500 miles.

I just checked the engine oil, and it's full and mostly yellow color. It's still closer to yellow than brown. So in short, looking at this, I wouldn't change oil soon.

Should I go with the app or the oil I see?

Comment: What does your owners manual say about the service schedule?

Comment: You are right to question this, 3000 miles is very low, the interval on most new cars is usually 7500 miles or above. You may want to check the app settings, it's probably something you need to change to match your car's oil change interval.

Comment: It is not unusual to do one quicker oil change when new to help capture any debris from manufacturing, but normally that would just be once.  In the old days, single weight running-in oil was used for the first couple hundred miles before you started using regular oil.

Answer (score 7):

I downloaded the [manual](https://uk.cdn.mazda.media/c9e1a746e71e470fb62691459e80b5b2/b5eb4815c58b4ca5975626cc2899ce77.pdf?xd_co_f=NTZmNDYxYWQtYjA2NC00YWMzLWFlMjAtM2I4NTdiZDkzMzA1&rnd=48d792&_ga=2.261611205.933068253.1653286159-339012995.1653286159&_gac=1.195483870.1653286663.Cj0KCQjwvqeUBhCBARIsAOdt45YtaRrc0X0h5iDxwMWrkEiDjpyIlcggX7ZEwax5kBNOvYX2uq-kJyAaAjxJEALw_wcB) for the car.
There are different service schedules for different countries.

Many countries like the UK have a 12500 miles schedule, whereas some hot countries are as low as 3250 miles.

Is the app configured for the country you live in?

Examples -

Every maintenance must be done when the display/wrench indication comes on.
The display/wrench indication will come on before reaching the maximum interval,
20,000 km ****(12,500 miles) or 12 months**, whichever comes first. (after the previous** maintenance)

For Vehicles in Burundi, Cambodia, Cameroon, Gabon, Georgia, Ghana,
Mongolia, Mozambique, Paraguay and Tanzania.
**Maximum interval 5,000 km (3,250 miles) or 6 months, whichever comes first.**

For Vehicles in applicable countries/regions, except Burundi, Cambodia,
Cameroon, Gabon, Georgia, Ghana, Mongolia, Mozambique, Paraguay and
Tanzania.
**Maximum interval 10,000 km (6,250 miles) or 6 months, whichever comes first.**

Comment: I live in the US at a temperate climate, so it really shouldn't be 3000 miles, at least under normal conditions. I last changed oil a few months ago, so I was really surprised how soon it came up. Thank you for all the details!

Answer (score 5):

Especially with a new, and I assume still covered by the manufacturer's warranty, vehicle you want to follow the owner's manual recommended service intervals and keep records of having done so.

It's not required, in the USA anyway, that you have the dealer do it, but you must follow the procedures/intervals if you want to keep your warranty intact.

As far as your oil change indicator, that's not definitive since someone may have neglected to reset it properly.  But you should have receipts showing the work being done.

Again, check your owner's manual for the interval and the type of oil to be used.

Comment: Yeah, it might be actually due in 7500 miles but it might have not been reset. I don't care too much about the cost, but it's a bit of an inconvenience to have to change it a few months after the last one. Anyway, thank you for all the info!

Answer (score 1):

You have clocked 3,000 miles since your last oil change and your app is alerting you to the manufacturer's recommended [Schedule 1 maintenance](https://www.mazdausa.com/static/manuals/2021/cx-3/contents/07020200.html) interval (severe).  It is most likely that in this case the indicator & app were not (or could not be) reset at 4,500.  Your particular car does not have some sophisticated, real-world sensor system that determines the actual condition of the oil at this moment.  You could therefore ignore the app's warning and start maintaining your own log of oil changes.

Do not, however, rely on the dipstick.  I've read many articles on the [Machinery Lubrication](https://www.machinerylubrication.com/) website and have learned that the appearance of the oil on a dipstick really tells you very little about the oil's condition.  It could be badly contaminated by water, debris, additive breakdown, sulfuric acid, sludge, etc. and you would have no idea based on color.  Even an expensive oil analysis by a lab can be misleading.  Personally, oil that is slightly brown on a dipstick looks horrible once you drain it into a pan and shine a flashlight on it.

As other users have posted, oil drain intervals vary widely depending on hot/humid climate conditions.  Other conditions that shorten intervals include dust, stop-and-go traffic, short trips under 15 minutes, cold weather operation, towing, heavy accelerations and a worn/poorly maintained engine.

Comment: With my older car, I just went with every ~5000 miles(checking around 3-4K miles) and it was fine, but it was an older car so I didn't care as much. I guess, it doesn't hurt to be on the safe side even if the oil looks fine. The app is probably making it up as you said, but oh well. Thank you for all the info!

Comment: You're welcome!  I am fanatical about maintaining my engine at peak performance, so I change the oil every six months whether it needs it or not.  After 35 years, I've found it's the only way  to ensure the car never consumes oil, develops gasket leaks, shaky idle, poor pick-up.